# usb_register_dev crashing linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, kernel, kernel-module

***This is for a class***, but we are stumped. We are currently writing a USB driver for a Logitech camera that uses USBCore. What's happening is we load the module, then when we connect the USB Camera, and the kernel crashes and gives us a kernel trace (below). After a bit of debugging, we are pretty sure it crashes on usb_register_dev within the probe function, but we can't figure out why. We were hoping that someone would have any helpful suggestions or to send us on the right path. We're not asking for answers, just guidance.

We have looked at all of our variable initalizers and based on our notes and skull examples, it looks alright. Below are code snippits to the important functions and the call trace.

Kernel (Custom school, but based on 3.2.34):

```
Linux ETSELE 3.2.34etsele #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 22 18:22:05 EST 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Init:

```
static int __init
usb_cam_init(void) {
  int result = 0;

  if ((result = usb_register(&cam_driver)))
    printk("usb_register failed. Error number %d", result);
  return result;
}
```

Probe:

```
static int
usb_cam_probe(struct usb_interface * intf, const struct usb_device_id * devid) {
  int retval = 0;
  struct usb_host_interface *interface;
  struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint;
  struct usb_device *dev = interface_to_usbdev(intf);
  struct usb_cam *usbdev = NULL;
  int n, m, altSetNum, activeInterface = -1;

  printk("kmalloc\n");
  usbdev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct usb_ele_cam), GFP_KERNEL); ///////////////
  printk("usb_get_dev\n");
  usbdev->usb_dev = usb_get_dev(dev);

  usbdev->class = (struct usb_class_driver *) kmalloc(sizeof(struct usb_class_driver), GFP_KERNEL);

  usbdev->class->name = "cam";
  usbdev->class->fops = &cam_fops;
  usbdev->class->minor_base = 0;
//  usbdev->class->mode = O_RDWR;

  printk("for\n");
  for (n = 0; n < intf->num_altsetting; n++) {
    interface = &intf->altsetting[n];
    altSetNum = interface->desc.bAlternateSetting;
    for (m = 0; m < interface->desc.bNumEndpoints; m++) {
      endpoint = &interface->endpoint[m].desc;
      if (!usbdev->bulk_in_endpointAddr && (endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_DIR_IN)
          && ((endpoint->bmAttributes & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK) == USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)) {
        usbdev->bulk_in_size = endpoint->wMaxPacketSize;
        usbdev->bulk_in_endpointAddr = endpoint->bEndpointAddress;
        usbdev->bulk_in_buffer = kmalloc(usbdev->bulk_in_size, GFP_KERNEL);
        activeInterface = altSetNum;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (activeInterface != -1)
      break;
  }
  printk("usb_set_intfdata\n");
  usb_set_intfdata(intf, usbdev);
  printk("usb_register_dev\n");
  usb_register_dev(intf, usbdev->class);
    //printk("Not able to get a minor for this device");
  printk("usb_set_interface\n");
  usb_set_interface(dev, interface->desc.bInterfaceNumber, activeInterface);

  return retval;
}
```

Structures and global variables:

```
struct usb_cam {
  struct usb_device *usb_dev;
  struct usb_interface *usb_inf;
  struct usb_class_driver *class;
  struct semaphore sem;
  unsigned char *bulk_in_buffer;
  size_t bulk_in_size;
  __u8 bulk_in_endpointAddr;
  __u8 bulk_out_endpointAddr;
  int errors;
  int open_count;
  struct kref kref;
};
```

Logs from kern.log:

```
Nov 26 11:25:15 ETSELE kernel: [  123.845972] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234188] kmalloc
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234192] usb_get_dev
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234194] for
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234196] usb_set_intfdata
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234198] usb_register_dev
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234450] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 6d742e65
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234506] IP: [<6d742e65>] 0x6d742e64
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234539] *pdpt = 000000002bf84001 *pde = 0000000000000000 
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234585] Oops: 0010 [#1] PREEMPT SMP 
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.234619] Modules linked in: usb_cam(O+) snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib videodev vtsspp(O) sep3_10(O) pax(O) autofs4 apwr3_1(O) bnep rfcomm bluetooth parport_pc ppdev tpm_infineon binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_realtek nfsd nfs snd_hda_intel lockd snd_hda_codec fscache auth_rpcgss snd_hwdep nfs_acl snd_pcm sunrpc snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd dm_multipath psmouse serio_raw tpm_tis mac_hid soundcore snd_page_alloc mei(C) lp parport dm_raid45 xor dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log btrfs zlib_deflate libcrc32c usbhid hid e1000e i915 drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit video wmi zram(C) [last unloaded: uvcvideo]
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] 
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] Pid: 3153, comm: insmod Tainted: G         C O 3.2.34etsele #1 Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq 6000 Pro MT PC/3048h
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] EIP: 0060:[<6d742e65>] EFLAGS: 00210206 CPU: 0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] EIP is at 0x6d742e65
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] EAX: ea9b8800 EBX: ea9b8800 ECX: 6d742e65 EDX: eb18dc90
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] ESI: eb18dc90 EDI: eb18dc90 EBP: eb18dc30 ESP: eb18dc24
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] Process insmod (pid: 3153, ti=eb18c000 task=eb30d400 task.ti=eb18c000)
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] Stack:
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  c144a1fd ea9b8800 eb18dc4c eb18dc44 c13b05df ea9b8800 00000000 ea9b8808
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  eb18dca0 c13b6be1 00000000 eb3bc0d0 eb18dc94 c11c5560 00000000 00000000
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  0000000a eb3bffff 00000001 14e7232a eb18dcd5 ffffffff eb18dc80 f7022208
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] Call Trace:
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c144a1fd>] ? usb_devnode+0x2d/0x40
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b05df>] device_get_devnode+0x5f/0xd0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b6be1>] devtmpfs_create_node+0x41/0x100
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c11c5560>] ? sysfs_do_create_link+0xb0/0x1e0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13aff3f>] device_add+0x1ff/0x620
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b9ae0>] ? device_pm_init+0x60/0x80
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b0377>] device_register+0x17/0x20
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b0431>] device_create_vargs+0xb1/0xe0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b048d>] device_create+0x2d/0x30
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c144a093>] usb_register_dev+0x133/0x270
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c15e8afd>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x5d/0x80
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<f98d81dc>] ele784_probe+0x17c/0x1bc [usb_cam]
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c14482ae>] usb_probe_interface+0xce/0x210
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b2815>] ? driver_sysfs_add+0x75/0xa0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b2a0f>] driver_probe_device+0x8f/0x2e0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c15e7392>] ? mutex_lock_nested+0x42/0x50
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b2cf9>] __driver_attach+0x99/0xa0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b2c60>] ? driver_probe_device+0x2e0/0x2e0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b1979>] bus_for_each_dev+0x49/0x70
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b2661>] driver_attach+0x21/0x30
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b2c60>] ? driver_probe_device+0x2e0/0x2e0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b22b7>] bus_add_driver+0x1c7/0x2e0
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c13b31d6>] driver_register+0x66/0x110
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c12e5912>] ? __raw_spin_lock_init+0x32/0x60
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c1447229>] usb_register_driver+0x79/0x140
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<f90bc01b>] ele784_init+0x1b/0x1000 [usb_cam]
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c103b3ef>] ? set_memory_nx+0x5f/0x70
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c1003035>] do_one_initcall+0x35/0x170
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<f90bc000>] ? 0xf90bbfff
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c10a3aeb>] sys_init_module+0x2db/0x1d60
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146]  [<c15ef79f>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x38
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] Code:  Bad EIP value.
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] EIP: [<6d742e65>] 0x6d742e65 SS:ESP 0068:eb18dc24
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.235146] CR2: 000000006d742e65
Nov 26 11:25:32 ETSELE kernel: [  140.361304] ---[ end trace 3f64a15c3c778575 ]---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `usb_class_driver` structure must be correctly initialized.

You could use `kzalloc` instead of `kmalloc`, but having multiple classes for multiple cameras would be wrong, so you should make the camera class a static variable (like in *every* other driver that uses `usb_register_dev`).